# Flutter Color.RGBO and adobeXD with same color values does not match?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change background color of Scaffold in flutter. I set the color as following

```
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 254, 100);
```

It's the same color I use in adobe xd during design. When I run application both color does not matching.

**Am I doing something wrong?**

[image: Adobe XD Design]
[image: Flutter Output]

Comment: Which color are you referring to? Is it the light pinkish color? It is not very likely that they would not match. Maybe they just appear different to our eye because of different background color.

Comment: Background color. I design UI in adobeXD and now I'm implementing in flutter. But color is not matching. It's not even close.

Comment: You need to share the relevant part of your code. Maybe some other widget with gray background is obstructing the color which you passed to Scaffold's background.

Comment: @JigarPatel you can clone the repo or check out here: https://github.com/abdullah432/happyshooping
Background code path lib/UI/home.dart

Comment: I checked (246, 246, 254, 100) is nowhere near to the intended color. It is a grayish color. So flutter app is showing the correct color. Maybe you made a mistake while taking the color values from adobeXD.

Comment: @JigarPatel please check again. 
backgroundColor: Constant.customColor4. All the colors is declared in Constant.dart file inside lib/Utils/Constant.dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want `opacity = 1`??

```dart
backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(246, 246, 254, 1)
```

Because

> opacity is alpha channel of this color as a double, with 0.0 being
> transparent and 1.0 being fully opaque.

See more in [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/Color.fromRGBO.html)

Comment: Looks like the right catch. This seems to be the fix for this. Somehow passing 100 as the opacity is affecting the color, whereas ideally any number above 1.0 should be considered as 1.0 opacity.